# Issue in adding an existing member to a group using directory api

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

```
static void addGroupMember(Directory client) throws Exception {
    String userEmail = "sample@mydomain.com";
    String groupEmail = "mygroup@mydomain.com";
    Member member=new Member();
    member.setEmail(userEmail);
    member.setRole("MEMBER");

    client.members().insert(groupEmail, member).execute();

    }
```

This is the code which i tried to add  an existing member (sample@mydomain.com) to a group (mygroup@mydomain.com). when I am executing the code it is only creating a label inside the group.it is not linking the label with the existing user. how can i map the label with the existing user

Answer (score 0):

For existing members, you should be using [PATCH](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/patch) or [UPDATE](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/update) methods to change the member's role in the group.